# Matlab Array Ops Optimization

Tags: arrays, matlab, optimization

In a MATLAB program I call many times (over 3 million) to a function that converts from local coordinates to global coordinates in an image, just a a simple transformation. My whole code takes 6 minutes to run, and the coordinates conversion function takes 20% of that time.

How can I optimize this code?

```
function LMP_glb = do(pnt_val,LMP,NP_glb)

    NP_co = ones(1,3)*round(pnt_val+1); 
    LMP_glb = [NP_glb(1:3) + LMP(1:3) - NP_co(1:3)]; %basic operations

end
```

Note: this function is called from several other functions in my code (not in a single endless for loop).

Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to optimize for the calling functions, as it doesn't look like it's doing much in this function. Calling it million times isn't helping it. Also, I think you can directly get `LMP_glb` as `LMP_glb = [NP_glb(1:3) + LMP(1:3) - round(pnt_val+1)];`. MATLAB would take care of the sizing thing that you are doing one line above it if `pnt_val` is a scalar.

Comment: I agree. Try to see if you can avoid calling the function in several places. Perhaps the results from one call can be reused instead of another call.

Comment: Yes may be you can pre-compute results for all coordinates once for all at the very beginning (+using vectorization in such case) and then pass these results as a parameter to all other functions (there will be no copy overhead as long as you're not modifying cached results in sub functions).

Answer (score 0):

You can make this a little bit simpler:

```
function LMP_glb = do(pnt_val,LMP,NP_glb)

    LMP_glb = NP_glb(1:3) + LMP(1:3) - round(pnt_val+1);

end
```

as MATLAB will handle expanding the last part of the expression from a scalar to an array for you.

I can't see much of a way to optimize it beyond that, as it isn't doing much. If you were to inline this (i.e. put the expression directly in your code rather than calling out to it as a function), you would additionally save the time taken in the overhead of a function call - if there are 3 million calls, that could be expensive.

@CitizenInsane 's suggestion is also a good one - if it's possible to precompute this function for all your coordinates at once, and then use them later, it might be possible to vectorize the operation for additional speedup.

Lastly, it would be possible (if you're comfortable with a little C), to implement this function in C, compile it, and call it as a MEX function. This may or may not be faster - you'd need to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your **do** function is called inside some kind of **for** loops. If your for loop doesn't have data inter-dependences, you can simply change it to **parfor**, and Matlab will start parallel pools to take advantage of multicore processor, i.e. parallel computing. Even if your data is interlaced inside for loops, you can do some trick to get rid of it ( declare addition matrix, array to hold another copy of the data structure, trade memory usage for speed).

As mentioned by Sam, you can rewrite the function using C/C++, compile it by Matlab compiler, and call the compiled MEX function directly. From my experience, C/C++ MEX function is faster than Matlab build in for simple arithmetics.

Parfor guide:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/getting-started-with-parfor.html

MEX example:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/standalone-example.html